# Functionality of a pure virtual function with variable return type - workaround/design?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, return-type-deduction

I'm working on a very, very simple data access layer (DAL) featuring two classes: `DataTransferObject` (DTO) and `DataAccessObject` (DAO). Both classes are abstract base classes and need to be inherited and modified for a specific use case.

```
class DataTransferObject {
protected:
    //protected constructor to prevent initialization
};

class DataAccessObject {
public:
    virtual bool save(DataTransferObject o) = 0;
    virtual DataTransferObject* load(int id) = 0;
};
```

in case of a `House` class from the business logic layer, the implementation of the DAL classes would read something along these lines:

```
class Dto_House : public DataTransferObject {
public:
    int stories;
    string address;   //...which are all members of the House class...
    Dto_House(House h);
};

class Dao_House : public DataAccessObject {
public:
    bool save(Dto_House h) { /*...implement database access, etc...*/ }
    Dto_House* load(int id) {/*...implement database access, etc...*/ }
};
```

*EDIT:* Of course, the derived classes know about the structure of the `House` class and the data storage.
Simple, nice, okidoke. 
Now I wanted to provide a method `toObject()` in the DTO class in order to quickly convert the `Dto_House` into a `House` object. I then read about the automatic return type deduction in C++14 and tried:

```
class DataTransferObject {
public:
    virtual auto toObject() = 0;
};
```

But I had to discover: No automatic return type deduction for virtual functions. :(

---

**What are your ideas about implementing a "virtual function with deduced return type" for this specific case?** I want a general `toObject()` function in my DTO "interface".

The only thing that came to my mind was something like:

```
template <typename T>
class DataTransferObject {
    virtual T toObject() = 0;
};

class Dto_House : public DataTransferObject<House> {
public:
    int stories;
    string address;
    House toObject() {return House(stories, address);}
};
```

---

**EDIT:**
A possible use case would be:

```
House h(3, "231 This Street");
h.doHouseStuff();

//save it
Dto_House dtoSave(h);
Dao_House dao;
dao.save(dtoSave);    //even shorter: dao.save(Dto_House(h));

//now load some other house
Dto_House dtoLoad = dao.load(id 2);
h = dtoLoad.toObject();
h.doOtherHouseStuff();
```

But the house does not know it can be saved and loaded.

Of course, the abstract DAO class may be derived to further refine it for the use with, e.g. Sqlite, XML files or whatever... I just presented the very basic concept.

Comment: What's wrong with template implementation? You anyway will not be able to polymorphically use `DataTransferObject::toObject()` if it has different return types...

Comment: I didn't judge the template implementation yet. If the overall tenor is "that's the way to go", I'll gladly go down that road. Wouldn't a class template design make DTO obsolete as I could implement the DAO as a class template with `virtual bool save(T t) = 0;` and `virtual T* load(int id) = 0;`?

Comment: It is not possible in way you want it. And it's pretty easy to understand why - all virtual overrides must return same type or, at least, same size type. Otherwise calling code wouldn't know what size will be returned. Possible solution - return pointer to object and cast it. In this case it'll be better to add some sort of ID for all DTO types to check is this object of expected class.

Comment: Can you propose your solution in a slightly more detailed example as an answer? I'm not sure, if I understand your approach...

Comment: You may want to consider covariant return types. You will have to return pointers or references, and your business classes like House will have to inherit from a common base.

Comment: Hmm...well, deriving the business logic classes from a common `Storable` class is what I wanted to avoid... For me it feels a bit like mixing business logic and data access.... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can not have a `virtual` function returning *different* types in different subclasses, as this violates the whole concept of statically typed language: if you call `DataTransferObject::toObject()`, the compiler does not know what type it is going to return until runtime.

And this highlight the main problem of your design: why do you need a base class at all? How are you going to use it? Calling `DataTransferObject::toObject()`, even if you use some magic to get it work (or use a dynamically typed language), sounds like a bad idea since you can not be sure what the return type is. You will anyway need some casts, or some `if`s, etc, to get it working — or you will be using only the functionality common for all such objects (`House`, `Road`, etc.) — but then you just need a common base class for all of them.

In fact, there is one exception to the same return type rule: if you return a pointer to a class, you can use the [Covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) concept: a subclass may override a `virtual` function to return a subclass of the original return type. If all your "objects" have a common base class, you may use something along the lines of

```
struct DataTransferObject {
    virtual BaseObject* toObject() = 0;
};

struct Dto_House : public DataTransferObject {
    virtual House* toObject() { /*...*/ } // assumes that House subclasses BaseObject
};
```

However, this will still leave the same problem: if all you have in your code is `DataTransferObject`, even if you (but not the compiler) *know* it is a `Dto_House`, you will need some cast, which might be unreliable.

On the other hand, you template solution seems quite good except that you will not be able to explicitly call `DataTransferObject::toObject()` (unless you know the type of the object), but that's a bad idea as I have explained.

So, I suggest you think on how you are going to actually *use* the base classes (even write some sample code), and make your choice based on that.

Comment: My aim is to have a set of classes as generic as possible to provide a simple possibility of data access at maximum separation of business logic as possible. I don't want the `House` class to _know_ it's gonna be saved later (or not). This is why I don't really like the "Base type concept" - although, if you tell me it's commonly implemented that way........? I can't yet really comprehend the return type/cast problem... a use scenario would look something like (see the EDIT in my question...)

Comment: @LCsa, the example you provide shows no need for base class for `Dto_Something` objects; you do not seem to use it polymorphically, so why do you want to have `toObject()` in the base class?

Comment: Because I would use the `DataTransferObject` (and the DAO as well) for *any* class that I want make storable (without telling the business logic for now - feel free to comment on that). So in an application, there might be `Dto_House`, `Dto_Student`, `Dto_4dVector`, ... (with their respective DAO implementations) all of which need to be saved but have nothing to do with each other. This shall become my personal, unified data access infrastracture.

Comment: @LCsa, ok, but how actually are you going to leverage the fact that `toObject()` is in the base class, not in each subclass? Can you post an example code where you really need it?

Comment: Hehe, the joke is that I want to force every child of `DataTransferObject` to provide a `toObject()` function. I say: *I create two classes - DTO and DAO - which shall give me the power to handle data access uniformly throughout my programs.* DTOs have to be able to create objects of the classes they're implemented for and DAOs (more or less specialised for different data stores) have to provide `save()` and `load()` functions, knowing how to deal with the classes they're implemented for.
There is no example since I'm still working on those classes, sadly. :P

Comment: @LCsa, I don't mean post some real code.Just try to imagine how you will be using it; it is anyway useful when you do the design, and especially useful if you want to make others understand why do you need `toObject()` in the main class.

Comment: I understand - I'm still convinced that such a function (and it's declaration in the base class) could be useful and I see it used, when thinking of an already existing application of mine (which handles data access quite inconveniently). I appreciate discussing (and learning by that!!!) about the topics, since I've neither lot of experience nor knowledge about programming (I come from an entirely different milieu). --- If I want to avoid data access-business layer coupling, then the template approach would be the one to go, it seems...?

Comment: Oh, and it just appeared to me: Is there a specific reason for your choosing `struct`s over `class`es in your examples?

Comment: And I just discovered that the template approach makes the usage of the generic `DataTransferObject` class in the DAO class extremely cumbersome... I have to declare templates everywhere...?

Comment: Maybe I'll go with the "no toObject() solution"... *every* other class would have to be a class template as well, otherwise...

Comment: @LCsa, the discussion now becomes rather long, and the comments are not the appropriate place for this. I think that you should better ask a new question, clearly specifying what you want to achieve and how are you going to use it, and see what people here would be able to say. Just be careful so that your new question is not classified as "too broad" or "opinion-based", do not ask some broad questions such as "What do you recommend", etc; instead explain the approaches you have and the disadvantages as you see them.

Comment: I'll try my best. Often I see myself confronted with conceptual problems rather than technical ones, hence my questions are prone to being "broad"... It seems to me that the programming community often doesn't like to present "basic concepts of how to do something". It is no reproach but an observation. Discussing with somebody usually helps me the most. Thanks again!

Comment: @LCsa, yes, because "basic concepts" are indeed a broad topic that is difficult to cover within one answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting an empty abstract class - practically, an interface, then have both of your types implement it and set this as the `toObject` returning reference type?

```
class Transferable 
{
    virtual ~Transferable() = 0;
}
```

And then:

```
class DataTransferObject {
public:
    //Return a reference of the object.
    virtual Transferable& toObject() = 0;
};

Dto_House : public DataTransferObject, Transferable { /*...*/ }
House     : public DataTransferObject, Transferable { /*...*/ }
```

The example above is to get my point.
Even better, you can use the `DataTransferObject` for this cause as your returning reference type, and no other abstract class:

```
class DataTransferObject {
public:
    virtual DataTransferObject& toObject() = 0;
};

Dto_House : public DataTransferObject { /*...*/ }
House     : public DataTransferObject { /*...*/ }
```

Update: If you want to have the classes separated apart, separating any association between data and operations by convention, you could set the name of the base class on something that represents the data i.e.: *Building, Construction* etc, and then use it for the reference type in `toObject`.

You can also have the class manipulating those operations on the API of data manipulation.

Comment: Next to the template approach, this sounds quite reasonable, however, I do not really like the `House : public DataTransferObject { /*...*/ };` part... Or am I overly concerned about separation of business logic layer and data access layer?

Comment: What restricts you from using an external, empty abstract class, in order for you to keep this consistency like the first example?

Comment: The idea of not wanting to let a class know that it's going to be saved to a data store... Separation of concerns and "stick to your stuff"... But, please, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Answer updated. Do not forget to upvote if any of the answers is useful.

Comment: This would of course be another possibility...however restricting this simple data access layer to the usage with this `Building` scenario, if you know what I mean. But anyways, I see certain different methods now and will try to choose a suitable one!